How can I manage the multilingual numeric keyboard in .NET Maui?
When changing my app's language to Arabic, for instance, numeric input no longer follows Western formatting (e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 with a comma decimal separator as in Italy), but appears as ٠ ١ ٢ ٣ ٤ ٥ ٦ ٧ ٨ ٩. My app's language is correctly set to "ar".
string savedLanguage = Preferences.Get(LanguageKey, string.Empty);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedLanguage))
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(savedLanguage);
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(savedLanguage);
}
else
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
}

However, I encounter an error when attempting to save an integer or double:
int number = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text);
The error message reads:
The input string '١١' was not in a correct format
How can I solve the problem in a scalable way for all languages??

You need to convert Arabic number. Check this answer about How to convert Arabic number to int?
